# Paho connection problem - Mosquitto: A network protocol error occurred when communicating with the broker

Tags: python, docker, mosquitto, paho

1. I run mosquitto (docker image - on external server)
2. After some period of time, my mosquitto does not work and show me this error (I do not know why)

> A network protocol error occurred when communicating with the broker.

3. When this mosquitto error occures and I try connect/publish, (python) paho.mqtt throws me this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
>   ***self.run()***
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
>       **self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)**
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   2913, in _thread_main
>       ***self.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)***
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   1578, in loop_forever
>       ***rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)***
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   1072, in loop
>       ***rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)***
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   1374, in loop_read
>       ***rc = self._packet_read()***
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   2071, in _packet_read
>       ***rc = self._packet_handle()***
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   2560, in _packet_handle
>       ***return self._handle_publish()***
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line
>   2728, in _handle_publish
>       **(topic, packet) = struct.unpack(pack_format, packet) struct.error: bad char in struct format**

4. It looks like my paho.mqtt.client is still connected but even if I restart mosquitto and I use mosquitto_sub (mosquitto error it's gone) I still do not see messages from my program. I need to restart program but it is not satisfying solution.

Could you tell me please, why mosquitto shows me this error and/or how can I catch (python) paho.mqtt socket.error (It's possible?)

I think that this part of code should be enought :)

mqtt_client.py

```
class MQttClient:
    client = None
    connected_flag = False
    loop_is_working_flag = False
    broker_is_online_flag = True
    subscribe_command_channel_flag = True
    mosquitto_ip = None

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config
        self.logger = Logger(config, self)


    def connect(self, ip_address='127.0.0.1', port=1883, keepalive=4):
        self.mosquitto_ip = ip_address
        self.client = mqtt.Client(self.config.get(REQUIRE_INI_SECTION, DEVICE_ID_INI_PARAMETER), clean_session=False)
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        try:
            self.client.connect(ip_address, port, keepalive=keepalive)
            self.client.loop_start()
            self.wait_for_connect()
            self.loop_is_working_flag = True
        except (OSError, ConnectionRefusedError):
            self.logger.error(CAN_NOT_CONNECT_WITH_IP_ADDRESS_ERROR.format(ip_address), send_to_mosquitto=False)

    def publish_message(self, message, topic, retain=False):
        return self.client.publish(self.config.get(REQUIRE_INI_SECTION, BUILDING_NAME_INI_PARAMETER)
                                   + '/' + topic + '/' +
                                   self.config.get(REQUIRE_INI_SECTION, DEVICE_ID_INI_PARAMETER), message, qos=1,
                                   retain=retain)

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc is 0:
            self.connected_flag = True
            self.logger.info(CONNECTED_TO_THE_MOSQUITO_INFO.format(self.mosquitto_ip), send_to_mosquitto=True)

    def on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc):
        if rc is not 0:
            self.connected_flag = False
            self.logger.error(DISCONNECTED_FROM_THE_MOSQUITO_ERROR.format(
                self.mosquitto_ip, str(rc)), send_to_mosquitto=True)

    def wait_for_connect(self):
        while not self.connected_flag:
            pass

    ...
```

And usage:

controller.py

```
class Controller:

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read(CONFIG_FILE_PATH)
        self.client = MQttClient(self.config)
        self.__connect_to_mosquitto()

    def __connect_to_mosquitto(self):
        if Network.host_is_available(self.config.get(NETWORK_INI_SECTION, BROKER_IP_INI_PARAMETER)):
            if not self.client.loop_is_working_flag:                
                self.client.connect(ip_address=self.config.get(NETWORK_INI_SECTION, BROKER_IP_INI_PARAMETER))
                time.sleep(0.2)
                self.client.publish_message(self.json_parser.get_json_welcome_data(), MOSQUITTO_TOPIC_WELCOME_DATA)

        else:
            self.logger.error(NO_CONNECTION_WITH_BROKER_ERROR, send_to_mosquitto=False)
            Network.restart_network_interface_if_there_is_no_connection(
                self.config.get(NETWORK_INI_SECTION, ROUTER_IP_INI_PARAMETER))

    ...

    def execute(self):
        while self.client.connected_flag and self.client.broker_is_online_flag:
            ...
            if self.client.publish_message(data, MOSQUITTO_TOPIC_DATA)[0] is not 0:
                ...
                self.logger.error(CAN_NOT_SEND_DATA_TO_MOSQUITTO_ERROR)
                break
```

I checked and this method returns 0 (success). But I do not get messages on mosquitto_sub

```
 self.client.publish_message(data, MOSQUITTO_TOPIC_DATA)[0]
```

Comment: You need to show us the code for your python client so we can see if you need to add some error handling

Comment: I edited my post and added some code :)